# Напечатать все слова, содержащие хотя бы две цифры. Python

Tags: python, list

Есть лист

```
words = ['One1', 'Two22', 'Three3', 'Four4444']
```

Требуется напечатать все слова, содержащие хотя бы две цифры

```
'Two22'
'Four4444'
```

Подскажите как сделать это через цикл и isdigit() ?

Comment: *как сделать это через цикл и isdigit() ?* Гм... а зачем? есть же фильтрация списков, есть проверка на соответствие шаблону.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самое простое, через `isdigit()` - так. Скорее всего можно более компактно

```py
words = ['One1', 'Two22', 'Three3', 'Four4444']

words_with_two_more_numbers = []

for word in words:
    numbers_count = 0
    for symbol in word:
        if symbol.isdigit():
            numbers_count += 1
            if numbers_count == 2:
                words_with_two_more_numbers.append(word)
                numbers_count = 0
                break

print(words_with_two_more_numbers)
```